# remove anaconda R from Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I have been using ipython notebook to run some R scripts. Now the problem is I have two R versions on my Ubuntu 14.04.
One is `R.3.2.2` at `/home/MYNAME/anaconda2/bin/R`,  another one is the R which I need for R studio, 
now the problem is I want to only use `R.3.3.1` for my system as I need some advanced task to be done.

I use `conda uninstall r`, after running this, according to the print out, a lot of R related packages is removed, if i run `conda uninstall r` again, it said

```
Fetching package metadata .......
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Solving package specifications: ..........
Error: no packages found to remove from environment: /home/MyName/anaconda2
```

but when I run `Which R` again, still it is the anaconda R, if I run `R` in the terminal, it is still `R3.2.2`, anyone knows how could I remove this anaconda R version?

Answer (score 1):

You probably needed to run `hash -r` in your session (or `rehash` if using zsh) to update your executables on PATH for the `which` command.  A new terminal session would also fix the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP and this did not seem to have any effect for me.

Comment: Nice one! I was unaware of the hashing mechanism used by `which`

Answer (score 1):

you can try `conda uninstall r-base`, this will remove R and all of the R-library.

Answer (score 0):

The questions also implies that one cannot use anaconda R with rstudio.

On Linux you can

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/R
```

and add to .profile (d/o your distro) to use rstudio with anaconda R and packages