# Why is R "hashed" to ${USER_HOME}/miniconda/bin/R?

Tags: r

I do not know how or why `miniconda` has hijacked my `R` environment. I just re-installed `R` to try to move past this situation. But `R` was still pointed to `miniconda` version:

```
$which R
/Users/steve/miniconda3/bin/R
```

So I tried to just shove that out of the way:

```
(base) 04:54:34/python $mv ~/miniconda3/bin/R ~/miniconda3/bin/R.miniconda
```

The new version of `R` "seems" to be the active one now:

```
(base) 04:55:21/python $which R
/usr/local/bin/R
(base) 04:55:24/python $ll $(which R)
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  9156 Jun 23 16:48 /usr/local/bin/R
```

However something funny happens when trying to actually run `R`:

```
$R
-bash: /Users/steve/miniconda3/bin/R: No such file or directory
```

I do not understand why the moved `R` is still being referenced. Is there some kind of alias or redirection for `R` ?

```
$type R
R is hashed (/Users/steve/miniconda3/bin/R)
```

Where is this defined? How do I change that to the correct `/usr/local/bin/R` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the "redirection" is actually due to the workings of `which`. This answer describes the situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/39009275/1056563

> You probably needed to run hash -r in your session (or rehash if using zsh) to update your executables on PATH for the which command. A new terminal session would also fix the problem.